# (iOS) Memory management for temporary variables

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

So the standard rule is if an object is created with alloc, copy or retained, it needs a subsequent release. Objects created with convenience methods are autoreleased.
But what about temp vars defined with "=" and used in the scope of a method? eg

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *tempString = @"foo";
int number = otherInt * 32;
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSArray *sameArrayDifferentPointer = otherArray;
```

or even

```
NSArray *sameArrayDifferentPointer = (*NSMutableArray) otherMutableArray;
```

I know the last one is 'bad' but compiles fine and doesn't throw exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`error`, `number` and `row` aren't objects (or pointers to objects) so they don't need to be (and indeed can't be) released. (`number` is an int, `row` is either an unsigned int or an unsigned long, `error` is a pointer to nil.)

`tempString` will be autoreleased—the line

```
NSString *tempString = @"foo";
```

is the equivalent of

```
NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithString:@"foo"];
```

Writing it the second way makes it clearer what's going on. Likewise, your arrays are the equivalent of calling `[NSArray arrayWithArray:otherArray]`.

Comment: How is the second case better? There's nothing at all wrong with assigning a constant string to a variable.

Comment: Of course not. And you're assigning a constant string to a variable in both versions. The more verbose one makes it clearer what's happening, which can be helpful for clarity. But my statement that the second is 'usually better' was probably too strong—will edit.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Very new to Objective-C and even C in general and the concept of pointers still tricks me up. Thanks.

Comment: Just one last thing, what happens if error is passed as a reference to a method such as stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error and error is no longer nil.

Comment: @GabrielRoth Different strokes, I guess. I tend to prefer the simpler version. Also, assuming that the two are equivalent is a mistake. It happens that when you pass a constant string to `+stringWithString` (or `-copy`) you get the same pointer back, but that's an implementation detail that you shouldn't rely on.

Comment: @TijuanaKez You'd pass the *address* of a `NSError*` there. If the `NSError*` is non-nil after the call, then obviously you need to deal with that error. But once again, you didn't `alloc`, `copy`, or `retain`, so you're not responsible for releasing that error object. (This is exactly what `autorelease` is for -- `+stringWithContentsOfURL:error:` will have used `autorelease` to take care of releasing the error that it allocated.)

Comment: @Caleb Thanks for the clarification—I was under the impression that using an = sign as an assignment operator with a constant string was compiler shorthand for `+stringWithString`.

Answer (score 2):

> But what about temp vars defined with "=" and used in the scope of a method?

The same rules apply. Did you `alloc`, `copy`, or `retain` those values? I don't see a single `alloc`, `copy`, or `retain` in the examples you provided. Therefore, no `release` needed.